# sidekiq queuing job twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Sidekiq is queueing a job twice. I have a link that is doing a get request to an action on the controller. In that action it is kicking off the job Workers::ReportWorker.perform_async(current_user.id). When I go into the sidekiq dashboard it has two jobs running for some reason. Could this be due to the fact that Im using a get request instead of a post? Also this is only happening in production not development. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: GET vs POST shouldn't matter.  Do your logs show the GET request being made twice?  It could be one of those "prefetch pages to speed up your browsing experience" preferences -- in which case switching to POST might help.

Comment: There is no view for it so it should really just be a post request. Because after the job is queued it just redirects.

Comment: can you post your sidekiq.rb configs?